# Boas práticas para serviços Rest

Tags: json, rest, restful

Quando fiz minha primeira API rest, defini minha estrutura JSON e retornava sempre essa mesma estrutura mesmo o par tendo dado ou não. Conversei com um novo colega de trabalho e ele me apresentou outra perspectiva. Se o par não tiver dado, ele é emitido para poupar tráfego na rede. Minha pergunta é: isso é uma boa prática?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com `par`? Pode apresentar um exemplo? Bem, pelo que entendi, isto não é recomendado e acredito que a economia de dados é insignificante na maioria dos casos. O contrato da sua API deve retornar (response) sempre os mesmos campos, pois omitir um deles leva a quebra do contrato e pode causar vários problemas de entendimento da sua API. Já na request você pode ser mais flexível sim, mas visando flexibilidade da API e não economia de dados.

Comment: Como boas práticas de REST você deve sempre utilizar os protocolos de requisição. Nesse caso que não existe dados você deve retornar o status code 204 que significa NoContent(sem conteúdo). Desse modo você respeita os protocolos de requisição e poupa tráfego de dados na rede.

Comment: @Dherik quando digo "par" me refiro ao atributo e seu valor. Exemplo: {"codigo":245}. Mas entendi o que quis dizer. Obrigado.

Comment: Se está preocupado com isso, nem deveria usar JSON, e sim um protocolo binário, e omitir tudo que não for informação de fato. O resto é besteira. Ou usa um padrão exatamente como definido, ou faz o seu de maneira inteligente, para atender seus requisitos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bem, pelo que entendi, você está falando de omitir um atributo nulo. Por exemplo, ao invés de retornar:

```
{
    atributo1: "Hello",
    atributo2: null,
}
```

Seu colega recomenda:

```
{
    atributo1: "Hello"
}
```

Isto não é recomendado e acredito que a economia de dados é insignificante na maioria dos casos.

O contrato da sua API deve retornar (*response*) sempre os mesmos campos, pois omitir um deles leva a quebra do contrato e pode causar vários problemas de entendimento da sua API. Já no envio (*request*) você pode ser mais flexível sim, mas visando flexibilidade da API (para fugir de um versionamento da API, por exemplo) e não a economia de dados.

Enfim, conforme o princípio da robustez (ou Lei de Postel) [nos alerta](https://martinfowler.com/articles/enterpriseREST.html):

> Postel's Law states that you should be liberal in what you
>   accept and conservative in what you send.

Answer (score 3):

Esqueça esse negócio de boas práticas. Só usa isso dois tipos de programadores: o que não entende o que está fazendo e vai usar tudo errado, ou o programador muito experiente e entende como uma boa prática deve ser usada, que ela é só um guia, muitas vezes com viés, que não leva em consideração o contexto onde está sendo aplicado, e só deveria dar uma ideia do que observar, nunca seguir cegamente aquilo.

Neste caso não tem como saber o que fazer porque não temos o contexto. Não sabemos se dá algum problema omitir (imagino que seja isso, não faria sentido ser "emitir" como está na pergunta) a chave do campo que não tem valor. Há casos que a interpretação de não ter o elemento pode ser diferente dele não ter um valor. Pode dar problema de versionamento, por exemplo.

Se quer economizar tráfego pode pensar em outro formato. Pode usar um formato que não precisa mandar a chave repetidamente, só um cabeçalho. Isto dá uma ganho absurdamente maior. Mas não pode ser usado em todos os casos. Pode fazer algum tipo de compressão, em alguns casos pode ser útil, em outros pode ser inócuo e ter outros custos que não compensa o uso.